# Can I use Django Channels to display MQTT messages in realtime?

Tags: python, django, mqtt, channel, django-channels

My goal is to setup a Django application, retrieving MQTT messages from a broker. (For example using [Paho MQTT Client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/) ).

It would seem to me that the asynchronous fetching of incoming messages would be a nice fit for the new [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). As this would provide an event driven setup.

My question is: can Django Channels indeed be a tool to bridge MQTT messages? If so: how could I set this up?

Answer (score 7):

I have implemented a [very simple interface between MQTT broker and ASGI](https://github.com/edigiacomo/asgi-mqtt). It's still experimental and has some limitations, but you can use it to fetch messages published in MQTT broker (or use the code as example).

Run the MQTT broker:

```
$ systemctl start mosquitto
```

Run the MQTT-ASGI interface (similar to [daphne](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/daphne))

```
$ asgimqtt my_django_project.asgi:channels_layer
```

Define a route in `my_django_project/routing.py`

```
from channels import route

from my_django_app.consumers import on_mqtt_message

channels_routing = [
    route("mqtt.sub", on_mqtt_message),
]
```

Implement a consumer (e.g. store the MQTT messages in database) in `my_django_app/consumers.py`

```
from .models import MqttMessage

def on_mqtt_message(message):
    # do something with the message
    MqttMessage(topic=message["topic"],
                payload=message["payload"],
                qos=message["qos",
                host=message["host"],
                port=message["port"]).save()
```

Comment: can you suggest me some material where I can read more about it as I want MQTT functionality in my django project. Also, I want to publish data from dajngo too.

Comment: where does the `channels_layer` in the asgimqtt command come from?

Comment: @TomTichy `channels_layer` is the ASGI channel layer instance, you can find an example here: https://github.com/edigiacomo/asgi-mqtt/blob/master/examples/example_project/example_project/asgi.py#L7. 

Please note that asgi-mqtt is based on channels v1.

Answer (score 0):

After coming here looking for help on this topic myself I created [chanmqttproxy](https://pypi.org/project/chanmqttproxy/)

Essentially it's a fully async Channels 3 proxy to MQTT that allows publishing and subscribing. The documentation show how to extend the standard Channels tutorial so chat messages are seen on MQTT topics - and can be sent from MQTT topics to all websocket browser clients.

I looked at MQTTAsgi (and credited it for inspiration) but felt that using a pure async solution with full Channels integration was more appropriate.

It may be a bit late to help the OP from 2016 but the comments show people are still coming here so it may be an option for future searchers like me :)